# Many-To-Many extra columns Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Has passed a week and I'm struggling with a problem and it seems that I'm not able to find any answer to it.

I have this structure:
[image: Database Structure]

`Album` model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DatabaseConstants.ALBUM_TABLE_NAME)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Album {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int imageVersion = 1;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean single = false;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Long deletedAt;

    // Relations

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AlbumView> albumViews;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

`AlbumView` model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DatabaseConstants.ALBUM_VIEW_RELATION_TABLE_NAME)
public class AlbumView {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean bigger;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int position;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Long deletedAt;

    // Relations

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "album_id")
    private Album album;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "view_id")
    private View view;

    // Getters and Setters    
}
```

`View` model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DatabaseConstants.VIEW_TABLE_NAME)
public class View {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Long deletedAt;

    // Relations

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AlbumView> albumViewList;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

I need to search a list of albums by an view. I that the query that I need is something like (Using `@Query` annotation from Spring JPA):

```
SELECT a, av.bigger, av.position FROM Album a, AlbumView av WHERE av.view.id = ?
```

But I can't map those two values (bigger, position) because they aren't on the `Album` model. I need to build an response like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Test Album',
        imageVersion: 1,
        description: 'Description one',
        single: true,
        bigger: true,
        position: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Test Album 2',
        imageVersion: 1,
        description: 'Description two',
        single: true,
        bigger: false,
        position: 2
    }
]
```

As far as I read, I can't use `@Transient` to help me here (because apparently JPA ignores it and the `@Query` don't fill those attributes) and I don't know other way to do it.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I tried the @bonifacio suggestion using the following code in the `Repository` class of Spring JPA:

```
@Query("SELECT av.album.id, av.album.name, av.album.imageVersion, av.bigger, av.position FROM AlbumView av WHERE av.view.id = ?1")
List<AlbumView> findByViewId(Long id);
```

But I got the following response:

```
[
    [
        1,
        "Test Best Hits",
        1,
        true,
        1
    ]
]
```

The values is exactly that, but it is considering that is an array, and not an object like its supposed..

Comment: Can't you select directly the AlbumView entity? `SELECT av.album.id, av.album.name, av.album.imageVersion, av.bigger, av.position FROM AlbumView av WHERE av.view.id = ?` ?

Comment: @Bonifacio it kind of worked, but not completely, I updated the question with the results

Comment: @augustoccesar The reason it has happened is because in mine example and in yours what's being selected is not the entity, but instead an array, if you select more than one column the result will always be an array, that's the default Hibernate's behavior. In this case you should select only the object entity you want: `SELECT av FROM AlbumView av WHERE av.view.id = ?1`

Comment: @Bonifacio It worked! Thanks! But just for the curiosity because you seem to master it :D If I want to filter some of the columns from the table to no bring all the object, is there an way to do it on the query (without it transforming it into an array)?

Comment: @augustoccesar I spot that JsonInclude annotation there which makes me assume a webservice is involved here. What do you really want to solve? What information you fetch from the database, or what information you expose in the webservice? If it is the latter, I'd rather focus on making the webservice technology do the work for you rather than JPA.

Comment: @augustoccesar Glad to hear that your problem was solved! As for your new question, you can do it in many ways. Usually I use either JsonObjectBuilder and select exactly what columns I'd want to send, or using "@JsonIgnore" annotation on the fields that I would not use in a Entity. However, I'm pretty sure that are many other possibilities, like using third party libraries and technologies ;). Also, I will include my answer so you can mark it as correct to help other SO users for laters cases, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by changing the query to select the AlbumView entity, which contains all the desired fields from both AlbumView and Album entity, and also can use the View entity in the WHERE clause of your query.

In this case, one of the possible solutions would be using the following query:

```
SELECT av FROM AlbumView av WHERE av.view.id = ?1
```

Also, I want to note that in your first example you were trying to fetch three different objects per row, like the example bellow:

```
SELECT a, av.bigger, av.position FROM Album a, AlbumView av WHERE av.view.id = ?
```

The reason that it does not work is because when you select more than one column (or object), you are not automatically fetching the desired fields in just one line, since Hibernate will convert the result in a Object array (Object[]) for each line of your query's result. So, unless you really need to select multiple objects in one row, it's always recommended to return only one field, or entity on each SELECT you make.